# random numbers from a small range without multiple repeats

Tags: algorithm, random

I need to generate random numbers from a very small range (sometimes just 0-1 ie a coin toss). The accuracy of distribution isn't particularly important but I do need to avoid long sequences of the same number.

I have tried generating random numbers using the C++11 std::uniform_int_distribution and while the distribution is very good, it can generate sequences of 15+ of a single value in a row (note that I don't really re-seed the RNG every time).

```
int randomInRange(int range)
{
    std::mt19937 rng(0);
    auto seed = std::random_device{}();
    rng.seed(seed);

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, range - 1);
    return dist(rng);
}
```

I built a test program (https://ideone.com/f9p0WJ) which showed that it could generate up to 18 heads in a row. I would like to reduce the probability beyond what the uniform distribution gives, for example halve the probability of a run of 3 and no chance of a run of 5.

Is there a generalised solution to this? My naive solution is to keep some history and discard when I detect too long a sequence (with some probability < 1) but perhaps someone smarter than me has already thought about this?

Comment: Actually, long runs must appear (with the appropriate frequency) if the process is truly random. If you artificially suppress them your numbers are less random (i.e. more predictable).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark if this is done each 4th number can be exactly predicted if you have seen the numbers before.

Comment: Do you mean "runs of 16 heads appear more often than they should" (about 1 in 16000) or "runs of 16 heads should never occur under no circumstances"?

Comment: @Henry yes I am not worried about the randomness - avoiding long runs is higher priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after isn't a pure uniform distribution, as @Henry said.

To enforce your constraint, I think that the best solution is to include a decay factor into your random number generator. As the sequence of numbers increases, the probability of that number appearing next decreases.

I implemented some prototype code in python 3, since my cpp skills are a bit rusty at the moment, but the basic concept is easily translatable to cpp. Here it is:

```py
def my_random(range: int, iterations: int, decay_rate :float = 2) -> List[int]:
    assert range > 0, "`range` must be a positive non-zero integer"

    if range == 1: 
        return [0] * iterations

    last_num: int = 0
    last_prob: float = 1/range
    
    rand_num_lst: List[int] =  []
    while iterations > 0:
        rnd = random() # generates a random number: 0 <= rnd < 1
        if rnd < last_prob:
            num = last_num
            last_prob /= decay_rate
            
        else:
            # The `int` function is converting the float into integer by 
            #    flooring the number
            num = int( (rnd - last_prob) / (1 - last_prob) * (range - 1) )
            
            if num >= last_num:
                num += 1
            
            last_num = num
            last_prob = 1/range/decay_rate
        
        rand_num_lst.append(num)
        iterations -= 1
        
    return rand_num_lst
```

Note that in Python3 the default division is float division, meaning that `1/2 = 0.5` instead of `1/2 = 0` as it happened in Python2.

I ran some tests to check the maximum sequence length and if the distribution of numbers generated by this is still uniformly distributed, and it seems to continue to hold those properties:

Running with `range = 2` and different decay rates:

```
decay_rate: 2.00000 max sequence length:  6 number count: {0: 499830, 1: 500170}
decay_rate: 1.50000 max sequence length:  6 number count: {0: 499455, 1: 500545}
decay_rate: 1.25000 max sequence length:  9 number count: {0: 500241, 1: 499759}
decay_rate: 1.12500 max sequence length: 11 number count: {0: 499799, 1: 500201}
decay_rate: 1.06250 max sequence length: 14 number count: {0: 500655, 1: 499345}
decay_rate: 1.03125 max sequence length: 16 number count: {0: 500495, 1: 499505}
decay_rate: 1.01562 max sequence length: 16 number count: {0: 500010, 1: 499990}
decay_rate: 1.00781 max sequence length: 18 number count: {0: 499748, 1: 500252}
decay_rate: 1.00391 max sequence length: 18 number count: {0: 499987, 1: 500013}
decay_rate: 1.00195 max sequence length: 21 number count: {0: 499503, 1: 500497}
decay_rate: 1.00098 max sequence length: 21 number count: {0: 500495, 1: 499505}
decay_rate: 1.00000 max sequence length: 19 number count: {0: 499451, 1: 500549}
```

Running with `range = 5` and different decay rates:

```
decay_rate: 2.00000 max sequence length:  5 number count: {0: 200314, 1: 199245, 2: 200213, 3: 199962, 4: 200266}
decay_rate: 1.50000 max sequence length:  5 number count: {0: 199372, 1: 199829, 2: 199937, 3: 200527, 4: 200335}
decay_rate: 1.25000 max sequence length:  6 number count: {0: 199373, 1: 199784, 2: 200561, 3: 200062, 4: 200220}
decay_rate: 1.12500 max sequence length:  8 number count: {0: 199752, 1: 199931, 2: 200579, 3: 200287, 4: 199451}
decay_rate: 1.06250 max sequence length:  8 number count: {0: 199280, 1: 200286, 2: 199688, 3: 200446, 4: 200300}
decay_rate: 1.03125 max sequence length:  8 number count: {0: 199577, 1: 199582, 2: 200652, 3: 199870, 4: 200319}
decay_rate: 1.01562 max sequence length:  9 number count: {0: 200442, 1: 199916, 2: 200142, 3: 199729, 4: 199771}
decay_rate: 1.00781 max sequence length:  9 number count: {0: 199784, 1: 200544, 2: 199921, 3: 199557, 4: 200194}
decay_rate: 1.00391 max sequence length:  9 number count: {0: 199920, 1: 199054, 2: 200303, 3: 200833, 4: 199890}
decay_rate: 1.00195 max sequence length:  9 number count: {0: 200011, 1: 200530, 2: 199806, 3: 200321, 4: 199332}
decay_rate: 1.00098 max sequence length: 10 number count: {0: 199741, 1: 199861, 2: 199822, 3: 200081, 4: 200495}
decay_rate: 1.00000 max sequence length:  9 number count: {0: 199717, 1: 199184, 2: 200182, 3: 200891, 4: 200026}
```

Of course you can explicitely code something like: if the running sequence has a length greater than `X`, just ignore the number and generate one different than the last random number. Although I'm not sure if this method would continue to be uniformly distributed.

Comment: I think this is the best solution (right after just accepting that sometimes improbable things can happen), but you should point out that those long runs are still possible, although even less likely than before.

Comment: @tobias_k added some tests I ran

Comment: As an aside, "last_prob: int = 1/range" is confusing Python to me, because last_prob doesn't end up an int?

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Here's my C++ implementation (with the same interface as the standard C++11 random number distributions), and improved test code. https://ideone.com/40f0Ry

Comment: @HamishMoffatt Not in Python3, the default of division is float division. In Python2 it would yield an int ya. I'll add that to the answer :)

Comment: @MkWTF it was the `last_prob: int` part that confused me. This doesn't force last_prob to be an int?

Comment: @HamishMoffatt Ups, it has been corrected! The environment where I was coding wasn't actually checking/enforcing the types. I wrote them to be easier for you to understand what was going on.

Comment: @MkWTF still, in Python 3.7 ```x: int = 1/3``` results in x = 0.3333 which I find confusing. But we're way off-topic.

Comment: @MkWTF there's a little bug: if you call it with range = 1, you still get 1 ~50% of the time. Still, random with range = 1 is not very helpful.

Comment: @HamishMoffatt Python is not a statically typed language like C and variants or java. The types defined by `<var> :<type>` are actually an after thought and are used more for documentation puposes than enforcing types. That's why you can do what you said.

Also, added a validation in the beginning of the function, and in case of `range = 1`, I'm simply outputing a list of zeros with length `iterations`. It is easier to handle this case as a separate one from the rest then integrating it with them. Thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my C++ implementation of @MkWTF's answer, with an interface compatible with C++11 std::uniform_int_distribution. (It needs reset() and others to be a complete C++11 `RandomNumberDistribution`.)

```
#include <random>

class decaying_sequence_distribution
{
private:
    const int min;
    const int range;
    const double decay_rate;
 
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist{0., 1.};
    int last_num;
    double last_prob;
 
public:
    decaying_sequence_distribution(int min_, int max_, double decay_rate_ = 2.)
        : min(min_)
        , range(max_ - min_ + 1)
        , decay_rate(decay_rate_)
        , last_num(min_)
        , last_prob(1. / range)
        {
        }
 
    template<class Generator>
    int operator()(Generator& g)
    {
        int num;
        double rnd = dist(g);
        if (rnd < last_prob)
        {
            num = last_num;
            last_prob /= decay_rate;
        }
        else
        {
            num = static_cast<int>( (rnd - last_prob) / (1 - last_prob) * (range - 1) );
 
            if (num >= last_num)
                num += 1;
 
            last_num = num;
            last_prob = 1./range/decay_rate;
        }
 
        return num + min;
    }
};
```